Telegram bot api, upload voice with reply parameters
I am working with the Telegram Bot API and utilizing its sendVoice method to send voice messages. Telegram Bot API supports GET and POST requests and allows specifying content types such as application/json and multipart/form-data. When using multipart/form-data, we can specify voice bytes and also include key-value parameters.
Specifically, I have a question regarding the usage of the reply_parameters parameter within multipart/form-data. In the sendVoice method, the reply_parameters parameter is expected to be an object that specifies which message the voice message is replying to.
My question is: How can I correctly format and send a reply_parameters parameter containing an object using multipart/form-data given that the reply parameter is not a primitive data type? I have been unable to find relevant documentation

you haven't mentioned any particular language you're working with. So, let's take it to basics and use cURL to send the voice.
curl -X POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOT_TOKEN>/sendVoice" \
-F "chat_id=1726826785" \
-F "reply_parameters={\"message_id\":<MESSAGE_ID>}" \
-F "voice=@<FILE_NAME>;type=audio/mp3"

Make sure to replace:

<BOT_TOKEN> with your actual bot token
<CHAT_ID> with the ID of the chat you want to send voice message to
<FILE_NAME> with the actual file name such as "audio.mp3" and optionally adjust the mime type as well.
<MESSAGE_ID> with the ID of message that will be replied to.

Here's an example usage:
curl -X POST "https://api.telegram.org/botBOT_TOKEN/sendVoice" \
-F "chat_id=123456" \
-F "reply_parameters={\"message_id\":8313}" \
-F "voice=@audio.mp3;type=audio/mp3"

Key thing to remember is, reply_parameters must be a JSON encoded String. The message_id field is required, please refer to the official documentation to find other supported fields.
You can use cURL converter to convert the curl command to actual code, here's an example one.

Or if you mention the language/package you're using, I can try to adjust the code to match your preference.
Hope this helps!

Thank you!
I didn't mention any language because it doesn't really matter. Your curl example is perfect
